# jQuery 3.1.1 memory leak on appendTo and empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I found a memory leak in my code that looks like next snippet

```js
function random() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
}

var _target = $('#target');
function add() {
    _target.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        _target.append('<tr><td>'+random()+'</td><td>'+random()+'</td><td>'+random()+'</td></tr>')
    }
}

var addInt = setInterval(add, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Memory leak test: jquery</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="target"></table>

</body>
</html>
```

The same code that is written by innerHTML doesn't give memory leak.
A tab with this code in Chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) has grown from 37 Mb to 161 Mb.
The problem exists if we use any of these methods in our code :

- .html();
- .append();
- .appendTo();
- .prependTo();
- .prepend();

I'm not sure about .remove() and .empty();
I couldn't find solution of this problem.
All the posts that I've found are too old.
Here is result of my test :
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't cause a leak on Opera 44.0.2510.1449 (PGO) or Firefox 53.0 (32-bit) but confirmed the leak myself on Chrome 57.0.2987.133

Comment: @ryad my target is  re-rendering the all table when i get a new message with new data by websocket.

Comment: This is still occurring on Chrome Version 58.0.3029.81 (latest update)

Comment: @webbm What operating system do you use?

Comment: @MixerOID Using Windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've this mem leak in Chrome 57, but in 58 all is fine!

- OS: Linux mint 17 x64
- Chrome: 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)

[image: mem leak test]